# NullReferenceException while calling LoginAsync

Tags: authentication, nullreferenceexception, hotmail, winrt-async, live-connect-sdk

In my WinRT app, I want the user to connect to his Hotmail account to access to his contacts. I use the [Hotmail API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/live/hh826535.aspx) from the [Live Connect SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/live/hh243641.aspx) from Microsoft.

To establish the connection, I use this [sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/live/hh826543.aspx#csharp) of code of the same documentation.

```
if (!Windows.ApplicationModel.DesignMode.DesignModeEnabled)
{
    authClient = new LiveAuthClient();
    LiveLoginResult authResult =
        await authClient.LoginAsync(new string[] { "wl.signin", "wl.basic", "wl.emails" });
    if (authResult.Status == LiveConnectSessionStatus.Connected)
    {
        this.session = authResult.Session;
    }
}
```

But the code raise a NullReferenceException in the method [LoginAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/live/hh694246.aspx). Here is the stack trace :

```
   at Microsoft.Live.ResourceHelper.GetString(String name)
   at Microsoft.Live.TailoredAuthClient.<AuthenticateAsync>d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.Live.LiveAuthClient.<ExecuteAuthTaskAsync>d__4.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at Project.View.TestHotmailConnection.<Button_Click_1>d__0.MoveNext() in TestHotmailConnection.xaml.cs:line 63
```

I don't think the problem comes from authClient because it isn't null when LoginAsync is called. According to this [post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/e897a135-52c7-45c3-bab9-2ee94803d876/), the problem comes from an uninitialized resource dictionary. Does anyone know this problem, and eventually how to resolve it ?

Thanks

**EDIT**

To use Live Contect in a WinRT app, you need to declare it in the [Windows Store Dashboard](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkId=233762), maybe it's the solution, I don't have a Windows Store account.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to register your app with the store. From VS go to Project -> Store -> Associate App with the Store

Comment: Yes, I think the problem comes from here, I don't have a Store account yet.

Comment: This didn't solve the problem for me. I am still getting a NullReferenceException on LiveLoginResult

Answer (score 0):

I have same issue with 5.6.2.0.

To fix it (as workaround) I put Microsoft.Live.pri and Microsoft.Live\SDKManifest.xml beside Microsoft.Live.dll (from https://github.com/liveservices/LiveSDK-for-Windows). Otherwise it can't get error description (for any error case, e.t. no internet, etc.) and crashes.

I've added a ticker for this issue. it looks like configuration issue